# Multiple assets in Flutter project

Tags: flutter

According to documentation to include image assets in a Flutter project, I need to add them to the `pubspec.yaml` like this:

```
flutter:
  assets:
   - assets/my_icon.png
   - assets/background.png
```

But I have ~900 images that I need to include in my application, do I really need to manually include one by one in the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, currently this is required and a known limitation.

[Wildcarding assets in pubspec.yaml (or allow an entire directory to be included) #4890](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4890)

You could use code generation to get the assets listed all at once,
but you'll also get into troubles when the list becomes too long.

Comment: See answer below, now allowed via assets/ without specifying

Answer (score 42):

Sadly, you can't import the whole assets/ folder at once but you can now import all the assets inside a folder.

```
# ❌ Don't Import every file inside assets folder, it’s tiring ❌             
assets:
  - assets/audio/celebrate.mp3
  - assets/audio/splash.mp3
  - assets/lottie/paper_plane.json
  - assets/lottie/celebration.json
  - assets/images/png/stats.png
  - assets/images/alert.svg

# ❌ Import all assets at once, Not allowed ❌
assets:
  - assets/        

# ✅ Just import every folder inside assets ✅
assets:
  - assets/lottie/
  - assets/images/svg/
  - assets/images/png/
  - assets/audio/
```

Answer (score 33):

This is no longer a restriction. You can now include all assets in a directory.

In the [flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#specifying-assets) it states:

To include all assets under a directory, specify the directory name with the / character at the end:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - directory/
    - directory/subdirectory/
```

Comment: This, however, does not (as of the time of writing this) work for subdirectories/folders which still have to be explicitly included/imported in the .yaml file  as defined here:  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27801 and here: https://github.com/onmyway133/notes/issues/513

Comment: recursive folders are not supported at this point :( very sad

Comment: Just don't forget to do "flutter clean" after any change in assets definition

Answer (score 2):

We can add images or any asset by ending its directory by `/` (Forward Slash).
Ex:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - Images/cars/
    - Images/animals/
```

It is a good habit not to add the whole "Images" directory at once.

Note:- Unlike any of the other programming languages, in YAML files we can't use the Asterisk sign ("*") to indicate a bunch of content.

Answer (score 1):

The flutter development tool named Flr(Flutter-R) can help you to auto specify image/text/font assets in pubspec.yaml and generate r.g.dart file.

More details see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61200175/1505549